# How to transform String Array to int Array with streams

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm making a simple class that takes an array of Strings and returns an array of integers with the length of each string in them. I'm trying to use the Java 8 Stream API to do it.

```
public int[] findMostSimilar(String[] words) {

    return Arrays.stream(words).map(n -> n.length()).toArray();

}
```

But an error appears in the stream itself indicating

> incompatible types, required: int[], found: java.lang.Object[].

Any ideas how to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Very similar/possible duplicate: [Java stream toArray() convert to a specific type of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902315/java-stream-toarray-convert-to-a-specific-type-of-array)

Answer (score 18):

First lets see why your attempt didn't work :

```
Arrays.stream(words).map(n -> n.length()).toArray();
```

The above statement returns `Object[]`. You could use `.toArray(Integer[]::new);` but then this would return `Integer[]`

---

Instead you can make use of [**`mapToInt`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) :

```
int[] array = Arrays.stream(words).mapToInt(String::length).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(words).mapToInt(String::length).toArray();
```